# Extracting key value pairs from a hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, erb

I have this hash:

```
{
  "results"=>[
    {
      "name"=>"Pete Gallego",
      "party"=>"D",
      "state"=>"TX",
      "district"=>"23",
      "phone"=>"202-225-4511",
      "office"=>"431 Cannon House Office Building",
      "link"=>"http://gallego.house.gov"
    },
    {
      "name"=>"John Cornyn",
      "party"=>"R",
      "state"=>"TX",
      "district"=>"Senior Seat",
      "phone"=>"202-224-2934",
      "office"=>"517 Hart Senate Office Building",
      "link"=>"http://www.cornyn.senate.gov"
    },
    {
      "name"=>"Ted Cruz",
      "party"=>"R",
      "state"=>"TX",
      "district"=>"Junior Seat",
      "phone"=>"202-224-5922",
      "office"=>"B40b Dirksen Senate Office Building",
      "link"=>"http://www.cruz.senate.gov"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am attempting to display the information in a view like this:

```
name Pete Gallego
Party D
state TX
district 23
. . .
```

and so on with each key placed before its value.

When I attempt something like this:

```
<ul>
    <% @my_hash.values[0].each do |key, value| %> 
      <li><%= "#{key.to_s} #{value.to_s}" %> </li>
    <% end %> 
</ul>
```

I get a view that resembles:

```
- {"name"=>"Pete Gallego", "party"=>"D", "state"=>"TX", "district"=>"23", "phone"=>"202-225-4511", "office"=>"431 Cannon House Office Building", "link"=>"http://gallego.house.gov"}
- {"name"=>"John Cornyn", "party"=>"R", "state"=>"TX", "district"=>"Senior Seat", "phone"=>"202-224-2934", "office"=>"517 Hart Senate Office Building", "link"=>"http://www.cornyn.senate.gov"}
- {"name"=>"Ted Cruz", "party"=>"R", "state"=>"TX", "district"=>"Junior Seat", "phone"=>"202-224-5922", "office"=>"B40b Dirksen Senate Office Building", "link"=>"http://www.cruz.senate.gov"}
```

I'm not sure why, if I'm printing the key `to_s` followed by the value `to_s`, that I'm getting the entire hash for each line item.  I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping the array but you also need to loop through each key-value pair in each array item (which is a hash). This will probably solve it:

```
<ul>
    <% @my_hash.values[0].each do |item| %>
        <% item.each do |key,value| %>
            <li><%= "#{key.to_s} #{value.to_s}" %> </li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can also do `@my_hash['results']` instead of `@my_hash.values[0]`.